# Bitwise Operation without operator and string

Tags: c#

I have this programming task to take an integer x and convert its value to binary than reverse it and convert it back to decimal and display.

I know how to convert it but how can i store binary value into integer without losing zeros. No string is allowed only integers.

Well i know how to convert it into binary(no rocket science)and reverse no problem but how to store remainder in integer.

Like x =12;
12 / 2 until remainder is zero. My question is how to store remainder in integer without losing zeroes.

Comment: Show your code first..

Comment: "I have this programming code". Where??

Comment: You could store the *count* of zeros you have in a separate integer variable. Or you could have an array of integers representing each bit or something.

Comment: I have a feeling that you are not aware of [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx).

Comment: @Jon i know these functions but no built in functions.

Comment: @poke No arrays only integers. I thought about using count integer but i would not know the exact place to put it back. Like 1100 and 1010 will not be same.

Comment: @user2838938 Is the length of those the numbers you want to reverse restricted? If you look at 32bit integers, you could easily have 32 integer variables instead of an array… <_<

Comment: I would look here for ideas. This code has been useful to me in the past: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel